# Setting up Spring + Maven on RSA (Rational Software Architect) with WebSphere

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I followed the tutorial at http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/ for getting this set up, but after almost two days I am still not able to get this running.

The error I am fighting is:

`[6/5/14 14:23:24:870 CDT] 0000001c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp commonInitializationFinally SRVE0266E: Error occured while initializing servlets: {0}
                                 javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0203E: Servlet [dispatcher]: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet was found, but is missing another required class.
SRVE0206E: This error typically implies that the servlet was originally compiled with classes which cannot be located by the server.
SRVE0187E: Check your class path to ensure that all classes required by the servlet are present.SRVE0210I: This problem can be debugged by recompiling the servlet using only the classes in the application's runtime class path`

And

`Failed to load listener: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`

My pom.xml:

`
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
        com.redacted.test
        Spring4MVCTest
        war
        0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
        Spring4MVCTest Maven Webapp
        http://maven.apache.org

```
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.version}</version>
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>Spring4MVCTest</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

`

I'm totally stumped on what to do here. I have spent a good 10 hours fighting this and have made zero progress. I have even rebuilt the project from scratch several times. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For some reason, markdown is not liking the pom.xml and screwing up the first few lines.

Comment: Why is your `outputDirectory` under "src"? Also, are you using Java 6 on the server? Where is RSA in your question (and what RSA are you referring to)?

Comment: I changed that because there were some warnings complaining about the output directory. The error is there with or without that.

And sorry, referring to IBM's RSA (Rational Software Architect). Their flavor of Eclipse.

Comment: I don't see modelVersion, groupId, artifactId, packaging, version or name tags in your pom. Are you getting a build artifact with this? Have you inspected he files within that artifact (is it a jar or a war)?

Comment: Those are all there, just markdown is screwing it up for whatever reason I can't make it work. It's creating a war.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be including a servlet-api JAR in your package? I have run into situations where an old version of the servlet API was unintentionally included in the WAR, resulting in similarly cryptic messages.

Comment: This is not the issue that I can see.